# get all of forms in project without create them as new object

Tags: c#, forms, controls

to have levels of `user access` for the users:

I have a form. it shows all of the controls exist in forms of win-project. until `admin user` can manage the controls in app by marking `checkboxList`.

I plan separate forms by `Dictionary`. Like:

```
Dictionary<clssMenu_Item, List<clssMenu_Item>>
```

`clssMenu_Item` save properties of one control in a form.

```
public class clssMenu_Item
{
    public string name; //control's name
    public string text; //control's text
    public string strKey; //Example: in 'MbtnAcc' = 'A' is strKey
}
```

so there is 2 levels in dictionary:

- btn1

  - btn1-1
  - btn1-2
- btn2
- btn3

btn1 - btn3 are in form A.

btn1-1 and btn1-2 are `buttons` in Form B, by clicking on btn1 from Form A.

I took a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815707 but wasn't useful for me. because declare a global variable and in this global variable exist forms which had opened before. so I don't have access to all of the forms in project.

I will glad to see your opinions...

Comment: Sorry it's hard to undertsand your question, what does:
I have a form. it shows all of the controls exist in forms of win-project. until admin can manage the controls in app by marking checkboxList.

mean?

Comment: @Master117 to give `user access`. I need a form which show all of the determined buttons. until `admin user` can manage app.

Answer (score 0):

you need to search with reflection

```
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
        select t;
```

Comment: How can use in `foreach` to get a property of form like `Name`? I tried `foreach (var i in q)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(i.Name.ToString());
            }` but didn't work.

Comment: hey my friend! I've never try reflection, please let me know how can use `q` ?!